# how to manage python dependencies like npm or java gradle

Tags: python-3.x

Now I have a `requirement.txt` like this:

```
# This file may be used to create an environment using:
# $ conda create --name <env> --file <this file>
# platform: osx-64
apscheduler=3.6.3=py37_1
beautifulsoup4=4.9.3=pyhb0f4dca_0
blas=1.0=mkl
brotlipy=0.7.0=py37h9ed2024_1003
bzip2=1.0.8=h1de35cc_0
ca-certificates=2020.10.14=0
cairo=1.14.12=hc4e6be7_4
certifi=2020.11.8=py37hecd8cb5_0
cffi=1.14.3=py37h2125817_2
chardet=3.0.4=py37hecd8cb5_1003
croniter=0.3.35=py_0
cryptography=3.2.1=py37hbcfaee0_1
dateparser=0.7.6=pyh9f0ad1d_0
feedparser=6.0.4=py39
ffmpeg=4.0=h01ea3c9_0
fontconfig=2.13.0=h5d5b041_1
freetype=2.10.4=ha233b18_0
gettext=0.19.8.1=hb0f4f8b_2
glib=2.66.1=h9bbe63b_0
graphite2=1.3.14=h38d11af_0
harfbuzz=1.8.8=hb8d4a28_0
hdf5=1.10.2=hfa1e0ec_1
humanize=3.0.1=py_0
icu=58.2=h0a44026_3
idna=2.10=py_0
intel-openmp=2019.4=233
jasper=2.0.14=h636a363_1
jpeg=9b=he5867d9_2
krb5=1.17.1=hddcf347_0
libcxx=10.0.0=1
libedit=3.1.20191231=h1de35cc_1
libffi=3.3=hb1e8313_2
libgfortran=3.0.1=h93005f0_2
libiconv=1.16=h1de35cc_0
libopencv=3.4.2=h7c891bd_1
libopus=1.3.1=h1de35cc_0
libpng=1.6.37=ha441bb4_0
libpq=12.2=h051b688_0
libtiff=4.1.0=hcb84e12_1
libvpx=1.7.0=h378b8a2_0
libxml2=2.9.10=h7cdb67c_3
lz4-c=1.9.2=h79c402e_3
maya=0.6.1=py_0
mkl=2019.4=233
mkl-service=2.3.0=py37hfbe908c_0
mkl_fft=1.2.0=py37hc64f4ea_0
mkl_random=1.1.1=py37h959d312_0
natsort=7.0.1=py_0
ncurses=6.2=h0a44026_1
numpy=1.19.2=py37h456fd55_0
numpy-base=1.19.2=py37hcfb5961_0
opencv=3.4.2=py37h6fd60c2_1
openssl=1.1.1h=haf1e3a3_0
pcre=8.44=hb1e8313_0
pendulum=2.1.2=pyhd3eb1b0_1
pip=20.2.4=py37hecd8cb5_0
pixman=0.40.0=haf1e3a3_0
psycopg2=2.8.5=py37hddc9c9b_0
py-opencv=3.4.2=py37h7c891bd_1
pycparser=2.20=py_2
pyopenssl=19.1.0=py_1
pysocks=1.7.1=py37hecd8cb5_0
python=3.7.9=h26836e1_0
python-dateutil=2.8.1=py_0
pytz=2020.1=pyh9f0ad1d_0
pytzdata=2020.1=pyh9f0ad1d_0
readline=8.0=h1de35cc_0
regex=2020.10.15=py37haf1e3a3_0
requests=2.24.0=py_0
setuptools=50.3.1=py37hecd8cb5_1
six=1.15.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
snaptime=0.2.4=py_0
soupsieve=2.0.1=py_0
sqlalchemy=1.3.20=py37h9ed2024_0
sqlite=3.33.0=hffcf06c_0
tk=8.6.10=hb0a8c7a_0
tzlocal=2.1=pyh9f0ad1d_0
urllib3=1.25.10=py_0
wheel=0.35.1=py_0
xz=5.2.5=h1de35cc_0
zlib=1.2.11=h1de35cc_3
zstd=1.4.5=h41d2c2f_0
```

now I want to install all dependencies using this command:

```
/home/dolphin/anaconda3/condabin/mamba install --yes --file requirements.txt -c conda-forge
```

but shows this error:

```
conda-forge/linux-64     Using cache
conda-forge/noarch       Using cache
pkgs/r/noarch            [====================] (00m:00s) No change
pkgs/main/linux-64       [====================] (00m:00s) No change
pkgs/main/noarch         [====================] (00m:00s) No change
pkgs/r/linux-64          [====================] (00m:00s) No change

Looking for: ['apscheduler==3.6.3=py37_1', 'beautifulsoup4==4.9.3=pyhb0f4dca_0', 'blas==1.0=mkl', 'brotlipy==0.7.0=py37h9ed2024_1003', 'bzip2==1.0.8=h1de35cc_0', 'ca-certificates==2020.10.14=0', 'cairo==1.14.12=hc4e6be7_4', 'certifi==2020.11.8=py37hecd8cb5_0', 'cffi==1.14.3=py37h2125817_2', 'chardet==3.0.4=py37hecd8cb5_1003', 'croniter==0.3.35=py_0', 'cryptography==3.2.1=py37hbcfaee0_1', 'dateparser==0.7.6=pyh9f0ad1d_0', 'feedparser==6.0.4=py39', 'ffmpeg==4.0=h01ea3c9_0', 'fontconfig==2.13.0=h5d5b041_1', 'freetype==2.10.4=ha233b18_0', 'gettext==0.19.8.1=hb0f4f8b_2', 'glib==2.66.1=h9bbe63b_0', 'graphite2==1.3.14=h38d11af_0', 'harfbuzz==1.8.8=hb8d4a28_0', 'hdf5==1.10.2=hfa1e0ec_1', 'humanize==3.0.1=py_0', 'icu==58.2=h0a44026_3', 'idna==2.10=py_0', 'intel-openmp==2019.4=233', 'jasper==2.0.14=h636a363_1', 'jpeg==9b=he5867d9_2', 'krb5==1.17.1=hddcf347_0', 'libcxx==10.0.0=1', 'libedit==3.1.20191231=h1de35cc_1', 'libffi==3.3=hb1e8313_2', 'libgfortran==3.0.1=h93005f0_2', 'libiconv==1.16=h1de35cc_0', 'libopencv==3.4.2=h7c891bd_1', 'libopus==1.3.1=h1de35cc_0', 'libpng==1.6.37=ha441bb4_0', 'libpq==12.2=h051b688_0', 'libtiff==4.1.0=hcb84e12_1', 'libvpx==1.7.0=h378b8a2_0', 'libxml2==2.9.10=h7cdb67c_3', 'lz4-c==1.9.2=h79c402e_3', 'maya==0.6.1=py_0', 'mkl==2019.4=233', 'mkl-service==2.3.0=py37hfbe908c_0', 'mkl_fft==1.2.0=py37hc64f4ea_0', 'mkl_random==1.1.1=py37h959d312_0', 'natsort==7.0.1=py_0', 'ncurses==6.2=h0a44026_1', 'numpy==1.19.2=py37h456fd55_0', 'numpy-base==1.19.2=py37hcfb5961_0', 'opencv==3.4.2=py37h6fd60c2_1', 'openssl==1.1.1h=haf1e3a3_0', 'pcre==8.44=hb1e8313_0', 'pendulum==2.1.2=pyhd3eb1b0_1', 'pip==20.2.4=py37hecd8cb5_0', 'pixman==0.40.0=haf1e3a3_0', 'psycopg2==2.8.5=py37hddc9c9b_0', 'py-opencv==3.4.2=py37h7c891bd_1', 'pycparser==2.20=py_2', 'pyopenssl==19.1.0=py_1', 'pysocks==1.7.1=py37hecd8cb5_0', 'python==3.7.9=h26836e1_0', 'python-dateutil==2.8.1=py_0', 'pytz==2020.1=pyh9f0ad1d_0', 'pytzdata==2020.1=pyh9f0ad1d_0', 'readline==8.0=h1de35cc_0', 'regex==2020.10.15=py37haf1e3a3_0', 'requests==2.24.0=py_0', 'setuptools==50.3.1=py37hecd8cb5_1', 'six==1.15.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0', 'snaptime==0.2.4=py_0', 'soupsieve==2.0.1=py_0', 'sqlalchemy==1.3.20=py37h9ed2024_0', 'sqlite==3.33.0=hffcf06c_0', 'tk==8.6.10=hb0a8c7a_0', 'tzlocal==2.1=pyh9f0ad1d_0', 'urllib3==1.25.10=py_0', 'wheel==0.35.1=py_0', 'xz==5.2.5=h1de35cc_0', 'zlib==1.2.11=h1de35cc_3', 'zstd==1.4.5=h41d2c2f_0']

Encountered problems while solving.
Problem: nothing provides requested brotlipy ==0.7.0 py37h9ed2024_1003
Problem: nothing provides requested bzip2 ==1.0.8 h1de35cc_0
Problem: nothing provides requested cairo ==1.14.12 hc4e6be7_4
Problem: nothing provides requested certifi ==2020.11.8 py37hecd8cb5_0
Problem: nothing provides requested cffi ==1.14.3 py37h2125817_2
Problem: nothing provides requested chardet ==3.0.4 py37hecd8cb5_1003
Problem: nothing provides requested cryptography ==3.2.1 py37hbcfaee0_1
Problem: nothing provides requested feedparser ==6.0.4 py39
Problem: nothing provides requested ffmpeg ==4.0 h01ea3c9_0
Problem: nothing provides requested fontconfig ==2.13.0 h5d5b041_1
Problem: nothing provides requested freetype ==2.10.4 ha233b18_0
Problem: nothing provides requested gettext ==0.19.8.1 hb0f4f8b_2
Problem: nothing provides requested glib ==2.66.1 h9bbe63b_0
Problem: nothing provides requested graphite2 ==1.3.14 h38d11af_0
Problem: nothing provides requested harfbuzz ==1.8.8 hb8d4a28_0
Problem: nothing provides requested hdf5 ==1.10.2 hfa1e0ec_1
Problem: nothing provides requested icu ==58.2 h0a44026_3
Problem: nothing provides requested intel-openmp ==2019.4 233
Problem: nothing provides requested jasper ==2.0.14 h636a363_1
Problem: nothing provides requested jpeg ==9b he5867d9_2
Problem: nothing provides requested krb5 ==1.17.1 hddcf347_0
Problem: nothing provides requested libedit ==3.1.20191231 h1de35cc_1
Problem: nothing provides requested libffi ==3.3 hb1e8313_2
Problem: nothing provides requested libgfortran ==3.0.1 h93005f0_2
Problem: nothing provides requested libiconv ==1.16 h1de35cc_0
Problem: nothing provides requested libopencv ==3.4.2 h7c891bd_1
Problem: nothing provides requested libopus ==1.3.1 h1de35cc_0
Problem: nothing provides requested libpng ==1.6.37 ha441bb4_0
Problem: nothing provides requested libpq ==12.2 h051b688_0
Problem: nothing provides requested libtiff ==4.1.0 hcb84e12_1
Problem: nothing provides requested libvpx ==1.7.0 h378b8a2_0
Problem: nothing provides requested libxml2 ==2.9.10 h7cdb67c_3
Problem: nothing provides requested lz4-c ==1.9.2 h79c402e_3
Problem: nothing provides requested mkl ==2019.4 233
Problem: nothing provides requested mkl-service ==2.3.0 py37hfbe908c_0
Problem: nothing provides requested mkl_fft ==1.2.0 py37hc64f4ea_0
Problem: nothing provides requested mkl_random ==1.1.1 py37h959d312_0
Problem: nothing provides requested ncurses ==6.2 h0a44026_1
Problem: nothing provides requested numpy ==1.19.2 py37h456fd55_0
Problem: nothing provides requested numpy-base ==1.19.2 py37hcfb5961_0
Problem: nothing provides requested openssl ==1.1.1h haf1e3a3_0
Problem: nothing provides requested pcre ==8.44 hb1e8313_0
Problem: nothing provides requested pip ==20.2.4 py37hecd8cb5_0
Problem: nothing provides requested pixman ==0.40.0 haf1e3a3_0
Problem: nothing provides requested psycopg2 ==2.8.5 py37hddc9c9b_0
Problem: nothing provides requested py-opencv ==3.4.2 py37h7c891bd_1
Problem: nothing provides requested pysocks ==1.7.1 py37hecd8cb5_0
Problem: nothing provides requested python ==3.7.9 h26836e1_0
Problem: nothing provides requested readline ==8.0 h1de35cc_0
Problem: nothing provides requested regex ==2020.10.15 py37haf1e3a3_0
Problem: nothing provides requested setuptools ==50.3.1 py37hecd8cb5_1
Problem: nothing provides requested sqlalchemy ==1.3.20 py37h9ed2024_0
Problem: nothing provides requested sqlite ==3.33.0 hffcf06c_0
Problem: nothing provides requested tk ==8.6.10 hb0a8c7a_0
Problem: nothing provides requested xz ==5.2.5 h1de35cc_0
Problem: nothing provides requested zlib ==1.2.11 h1de35cc_3
Problem: nothing provides requested zstd ==1.4.5 h41d2c2f_0
```

the mamba is compatible with conda, the requirement.tex is export by conda, what should I do to fix it? is it possible to make the dependencies version simple? what is the `=pyhb0f4dca_0` refer to?

Answer (score 1):

I think this `requirements.txt` isn't formatted correctly
it should be something like that

```
ordereddict==1.1
argparse==1.2.1
python-dateutil==2.2
matplotlib==1.3.1
nose==1.3.0
numpy==1.8.0
pymongo==3.3.0
psutil>=2.0
```

then you can install all dependencies using pip
`pip3 install -r requirements.txt`